# How to get non-matching records from two tables

Tags: mysql

See these two sample tables:

Table 1:

```
id    acc_no    name
------------------------
1     14        aaaa
2     16        bbbb
3     18        ccccc
4     25        wwww
5     27        xxxxxxx
6     28        zzzzzzz
```

Table 2:

```
sr no   acc_no  amount
----------------------
1       14      2000
2       16      2344
3       18      3200
```

I need to get records on basis of acc_no which are not matching in table 1 for example:

OUTPUT:

```
id   acc_no   name
---------------------
4    25       wwww
5    27       xxxxxxx
6    28       zzzzzzz
```

When I tried with below query ,the result was not reliable:

```
SELECT t1.* 
FROM table1 t1
     LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.acc_no = t2.acc_no
WHERE t2.acc_no IS NULL
```

Give your suggestions. What will be right SQL query ti get above output?

Comment: why the result was not reliable?

Comment: your query is correct. what's the problem?

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c63e7/1    It works fine

Answer (score 12):

try:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1 t1
WHERE t1.acc_no NOT IN (SELECT acc_no FROM table2)
```

Answer (score 11):

Should be :

```
select t1.id,t1.acc_no,t1.name from table1 t1
     left outer join table2 t2 on t1.acc_no = t2.acc_no
       where
     t2.id is null
```

Comment: @Devand Rathod: this only works if the Id field in both tables are related - for instance Table 1 Id is foreign key in Table 2. Judging from the poster's example code  it is not clear (although possible)  that this is the case.

Comment: ya its right , but what about acc_no ? if you use acc_no then ?

Comment: you can use acc_no , as i know.

Comment: Sure - that's the code which the poster has shown. And it should work as is. The poster has not defined why he thinks he's not getting reliable results.

Answer (score 1):

Try  this one also:

```
select t1.* from table1 t1 where 
    not exists (
    select 1 from table2 t2 
    where t1.acc_no=t2.acc_no
    )
```